# How to add coordinate system to SPOT imagery mask files?

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, gdal-translate, gml, gdalogr

I'm working with SPOT 6 and 7 imagery delivered in DIMAP format. I've figured out how to extract the multispectral and pan-chromatic bands into geotiff with `gdal-translate` so they're easier to work with.

In each archive there are a series of mask files in [gml](/questions/tagged/gml) format, which I can read with `ogrinfo` and Qgis. However the mask files don't have a coordinate system so I can't use them with the images.

From the ogrinfo report it appears the GML are using image row and column pixel dimensions. (The matching source image is 9652 x 57083.)

```
$ ogrinfo \SPOT6_sample_roi.gml maskfeature
INFO: Open of `\SPOT6_sample_roi.gml'
      using driver `GML' successful.
Metadata:
  NAME=Area of interest mask for product id SPOT6_MS_201308032015087_SEN_SPOT6_20160316_1601281mdxzlrvssw12_1

Layer name: MaskFeature
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (1.000000, 1.000000) - (9653.000000, 57084.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
maskType: String (18.0)
OGRFeature(MaskFeature):0
  gml_id (String) = REGION_OF_INTEREST-0
  maskType (String) = REGION_OF_INTEREST
  POLYGON ((9645.1767578125 6.41328716278076,9645.162109375 5.32240867614746,9645.03125 4.30024194717407,9644.7841796875 3.2741334438324,9644.5390625 2.39344930648804,9644.181640625 1.72693908214569,9643.7666015625 1.20388793945312,9643.4931640625 1.0,8939.99609375 1.0,1.0 4.3671669960022,1.0 28542.5,1 57084,9653 57084,9653.0 45960.265625,9645.1767578125 6.41328716278076))
```

[The gdalinfo report for the source image](https://gist.github.com/maphew/513404f56b956ef3f1379b70d1d5d87f) also shows pixel coordinates for the coordinate system:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,57083.0)
Upper Right ( 9652.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 9652.0,57083.0)
Center      ( 4826.0,28541.5)
```

However it also has RPC metadata that seems to be enough to have Qgis and ArcMap/Pro display it in the right geographical location:

```
RPC Metadata:
  HEIGHT_OFF=500.0
  HEIGHT_SCALE=500.0
  LAT_OFF=64.90742355
  LAT_SCALE=1.71583845
  ...snip...
  SAMP_OFF=4825
  SAMP_SCALE=4826.0
```

Sample files at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/119QEECJ42FKt0A9mq55rRmGsT9-5nSZq?usp=sharing
(The image has been resized to 10% of it's original size.)

**How might I marry the raster coordinate system info to the mask files so I can use them together?**

Answer (score 0):

A small piece of progress: we can use `gdaltransform -rpc` to get lat-long (or any other coordinate system) results for the pixel locations of the image:

```
$ gdaltransform -rpc DS_SPOT6_201308032015087_LM1_FR1_FR1_FR1_W137N65_10315\PROD_SPOT6_001\VOL_SPOT6_001_A\IMG_SPOT6_MS_001_A\DIM_SPOT6_MS_201308032015087_SEN_1.XML
Enter column line values separated by space, and press Return.
0.0 57083.0
-137.766376889524 63.1915449659547 0
9652.0    0.0
-136.420879379204 66.6213864498263 0
```

These are the corner coordinates of the gdalinfo report, and they match the image as ArcMap displays it.

[image: corner coordinates displayed over satellite image]

So in python we could loop through the vertices of each GML polygon coordinate pair and transform using the above method, but it seems there should be a more straightforward path.